# Understanding "qu’il pourrait lui arriver malheur d’avoir été désobéissante"

Tags: expressions, genre

The question is on the highlighted clause in this passage from Perrault's Barbe-Bleue.

> Elle fut si pressée de sa curiosité, que sans considérer qu’il était malhonnête de quitter sa compagnie, elle y descendit par un petit escalier dérobé, et avec tant de précipitation, qu’elle pensa se rompre le cou deux ou trois fois. Étant arrivée à la porte du cabinet, elle s’y arrêta quelque temps, songeant à la défense que son mari lui avait faite, et considérant **qu’il pourrait lui arriver malheur d’avoir été désobéissante** ; mais la tentation était si forte qu’elle ne put la surmonter : elle prit donc la petite clef, et ouvrit en tremblant la porte du cabinet.

**Question**

1. What is the subject of the clause?  Is it *il* or *malheur*?
2. Do we say, *il pourrait lui arriver joie de...* or *elle pourrait lui arriver joie de...*?

**Background**

For 1:  In *il pleut* one might be more inclined to say *il* was the subject because there is no obvious conspicuous alternative although one could also say *il pleut* does not have a subject.

For 2:  I am wondering whether the dummy placeholder has any obligation to track the gender of the real substantive to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in suspecting that there is no real subject. The construction "Il pourrait arriver [quelque chose]" is similar to "il pleut", "il y a", in that the subject "il" exists only to satisfy the grammatical need for a subject.

This dummy placeholder is always "il"; never feminine, never plural.

"Il pourrait [lui] arriver" can be followed by a number of objects, such as "malheur", "une bricole" (meaning something minor but annoying), "quelque chose {de bien, de désagréable, ...}", and even "une bonne chose" but "joie" and even "bonheur" seem very strange. I think the construction is very set and does not admit much variation. Any variation would depend on "quelque chose": "quelque chose de ..." or "quelque chose qui ..."